# Kernels and weights in Convolutional neural networks

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have seen a CNN code which uses kernels and weights
What is the difference between kernels and weights?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: we might move it to Data Science or Cross Validated instead, since it is more related to machine learning concepts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the difference between kernels and weights?

For CNN kernel (or filter) is simply put group of weights shared all over the input space. So if you imagine matrix of weights, if you then imagine smaller sliding 'window' in that matrix, then that sliding window is group of enclosed weights or kernel.

In the borrowed image below you can see:

- individual rectangle represents weight
- full set of input weights (input weight matrix)
- subset of weights or 'window' that we are 'sliding' across input matrix is kernel
- resulting output weight matrix

[image: I've borrowed image here to illustrate kernel/weight difference]

Comment: Ok now I understand. So it is necessary to use kernel in CNN together with the weights in every layer?

Comment: Well, it depends on your model and data, but if you want to include specific features (edge detection, vertical/horizontal edges and such) then you will need to use kernel (or filter). Good reference for understanding it is given [on this link](https://mlnotebook.github.io/post/CNN1/)

Comment: ok i got it.thank you!!